How to add the more than 2 color schemes in theme palette like light, dark, abc ,def? Not accepting anything other than light and dark
I am using mui version 5.11.13. I have configured my theme.tsx as below.
Also tried by augmenting module.
import { experimental_extendTheme as extendTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface ColorSchemeOverrides {
    customTheme1: true;
    customTheme2: true;
  }
}

const Theme = extendTheme({
    colorSchemes: {
        light: {
            palette: {
                primary: {
                    main: "#313E48",
                }
            }
        },
        dark: {
            palette: {
                primary: {
                    main: "#FFFFFF",
                }
            }
        },
        customTheme1:{
            palette: {
                primary: {
                    main: "#000000",
                }
            }
        }
        customTheme2:{
            palette: {
                primary: {
                    main: "#BBBBBB",
                }
            }
        }
    },
});


If I configured like this, then I am getting below error.

How can I fix it?

Problem might not be in this file
